# In Google Analytics, how can I plot behavior over time (example: Session Duration)

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to plot or graph "Behavior" over time?

In particular Audience->Behavior->Engagement->Session Duration.  I'd like to know if we're getting better or worse.  So far I've found a way to compare two periods, but not to plot the trend.

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by dm-guy is OK, but... having an average is not useful.

So, I see two ways:

a) build a custom report with:
 - metric: sessions (ga:sessions)
 - dimension: session duration (ga:sessionsDuretionBucket)

Add second dimension: date (ga:date), export to Excel and made a graph ;)

(You can use also Google Analytics Query Explorer 2)

b) create a segment with a condition on time on site (session duration) important for you. E.g. session duration between 10 s - 600 s

When you apply that segment on acquisition report, you've got what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom report in the following way:

[image: session duration report]

Then you will see it like this:

[image: graph session duration]

For a better analysis, look at the data per week, or per month. If you want to plot a trendline, then you can download it to excel (on daily, weekly, or monthly basis).

I like to analyze the session duration data by breaking it down to different campaigns. But you can choose any other dimension you'd like. You can instead put a "Page" or page groups if you are doing changes that suppose to increase duration on specific page or section of your site.

Also, consider to add a filter that exclude the bounced sessions, that is, that their session duration equal to 0 (or had no interaction on page, depends on your event tracking).

Answer (score 0):

There is a drop down on the Audience Overview report that can  be used to change the metric that is plotted.   Simply use the drop down menu to change the metric to anything you desire including "Avg Session Duration":

[image: Avg Session Duration]